# Mariadb Mysql deadlock without transaction

Tags: mysql, mariadb, deadlock

I have a weird situation. I have mysql/mariadb script which is simply collecting row count aggregated by date from a bunch of tables and inserting it into newly created table. No transactions. No locks. Simple insert from select. And I am always getting deadlock error at the beginning of a second 'insert' statement. My script is:

```
drop table if exists history_count_table;

CREATE TABLE `history_count_table` (
  `itemid` integer unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(14) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `count` integer unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
  `dbsize` integer unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert into `history_count_table`
 select itemid,date(from_unixtime(clock)) as date
 ,'float' as type, count(*) as count
 ,count(*) * 80 as dbsize
from `history group by itemid,date;

insert into `history_count_table`
 select itemid,date(from_unixtime(clock)) as date
 , 'uint' as type, count(*) as count
 , count(*) * 80 as dbsize
from history_uint group by itemid,date;

(... similiar insert from update from other tables follow)
```

Immediately upon entering second insert statement I am getting the "deadlock occured" error from mariadb. How on earth can deadlock occur when there is no lock. And the inserts are non competing. They are fully sequential.

Comment: Is the missing backtick after ```\`history``` in the first insert a cut/paste problem or an actual typo?

Comment: yes, cut/paste problem. the name was much longer, I have shortened it.